# SQL SP sp_executesql Just return int to entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my part of my SP code:

```
set @strSql = 'select Count(id) as CountId, FirstRouteNo,ThroughRouteSid,LastRouteNo,'
        set @strSql +='(select top 1 ThroughRouteJson from'+@tableName+'as subQuery where mainQuery.FirstRouteNo=subQuery.FirstRouteNo and mainQuery.ThroughRouteSid = subQuery.ThroughRouteSid and mainQuery.LastRouteNo = subQuery.LastRouteNo) as DetailJson,'+' '
        set @strSql +='(select top 1 RouteMeter from'+@tableName+'as subQuery where mainQuery.FirstRouteNo=subQuery.FirstRouteNo and mainQuery.ThroughRouteSid = subQuery.ThroughRouteSid and mainQuery.LastRouteNo = subQuery.LastRouteNo) as RouteMeter'+' '
        set @strSql +='from'+@tableName+'as mainQuery where [OperateDate] >='+QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(10),@startMonth,20),'''')+' and [OperateDate] <'+QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(10),@endMonth,20),'''')+' and'+' '
        set @strSql +='[FirstAbsoluteBoardStopId] in '+@StringStartVillageStopSid+' and [LastAbsoluteAlightStopId] in '+@StringEndVillageStopSid+' '
        set @strSql +='group by mainQuery.[FirstRouteNo],mainQuery.[ThroughRouteSid],mainQuery.[LastRouteNo]'+' '
        set @strSql +='order by CountId desc'           
        execute sp_executesql  @StrSql
```

This is my part of code in Visual studio. Just return int

```
   public virtual int GetVillageTransferData(Nullable<System.DateTime> startMonth, Nullable<System.DateTime> endMonth, string startTime, string endTime, string dateString, string analysisType, string isAllDay, string startVillageName, string endVillageName, Nullable<int> transferCount)
    {
        var startMonthParameter = startMonth.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("startMonth", startMonth) :
            new ObjectParameter("startMonth", typeof(System.DateTime));

        var endMonthParameter = endMonth.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("endMonth", endMonth) :
            new ObjectParameter("endMonth", typeof(System.DateTime));

        var startTimeParameter = startTime != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("startTime", startTime) :
            new ObjectParameter("startTime", typeof(string));

        var endTimeParameter = endTime != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("endTime", endTime) :
            new ObjectParameter("endTime", typeof(string));

        var dateStringParameter = dateString != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("dateString", dateString) :
            new ObjectParameter("dateString", typeof(string));

        var analysisTypeParameter = analysisType != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("analysisType", analysisType) :
            new ObjectParameter("analysisType", typeof(string));

        var isAllDayParameter = isAllDay != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("IsAllDay", isAllDay) :
            new ObjectParameter("IsAllDay", typeof(string));

        var startVillageNameParameter = startVillageName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("startVillageName", startVillageName) :
            new ObjectParameter("startVillageName", typeof(string));

        var endVillageNameParameter = endVillageName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("endVillageName", endVillageName) :
            new ObjectParameter("endVillageName", typeof(string));

        var transferCountParameter = transferCount.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("transferCount", transferCount) :
            new ObjectParameter("transferCount", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("GetVillageTransferData", startMonthParameter, endMonthParameter, startTimeParameter, endTimeParameter, dateStringParameter, analysisTypeParameter, isAllDayParameter, startVillageNameParameter, endVillageNameParameter, transferCountParameter);
    }
}
```

> It's my SQL Management query result.I want to get the same result in
>   My Visual Studio

[image: It's my SQL Management query result.I want to get the same result in My Visual Studio]
This is part of my code for SQL SP.I want to return all the data what
is my query result.I can see the all the result data in my SQL
Management Studio. but I just see SQL Management Studio  return int to
My entity framework.SO I want to ask How do I fix it to get all my
query data? Thanks

Comment: what does your actual SQL return if you run it? if you want more than in int returned the function only returns int so youd need to change it..

Comment: @BugFinder Hi,I put I the my query result picture from my SQL Management. I can't get all of my query result data to my Visual Studio?

Comment: and what would be the returned int your function gives at that point? Im thinking 3?

Comment: [`ExecuteFunction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986915(v=vs.110).aspx): "Executes a stored procedure or function that is defined in the data source and expressed in the conceptual model; **discards any results returned from the function**; and returns the number of rows affected by the execution." (My **emphasis**)

Comment: return number 23(int),I think that the result just return affect rows.Like  @Damien_The_Unbeliever said. But I Just query to SQL. I want to get all my query data. How can I reached that in my dynamic string query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.ExecuteFunction<T>()` instead of `.ExecuteFunction()`.
See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executefunction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Make a result class that represents your result, such as

```
public class VillageTransferResult {
    public int CountId { get; set; }
    public int FirstRouteNo { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Change

```
public virtual int GetVillageTransferData(...)
```

to

```
public virtual ObjectResult<VillageTranferResult> GetVillageTransferData(...)
```

Finally, use

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<VillageTransferResult>("GetVillageTransferData", ...);
```

instead of

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("GetVillageTransferData", ...);
```

Comment: I don't understand. Because Visual Studio code is automatically generated.when I add Sp to my Visual Studio project. I need to change automatically generated code?

Comment: The problem is that you're building a query in your stored procedure. EF will not be able to map the result generated by sp_executesql into a class.

I suggest that you put something like the above in a partial class with the same name as your current context (DbContext) class to prevent the generator from overwriting it.